# Magento 2 : Is there any idea how product will come in mailchimp after connect my magento with mailchimp?

Tags: magento2, product, email

I just need to use Product Recommendations block in mailchimp account. My magento store is already connected with mailchimp account but i can not seen any product inside this product block in mailchimp.

[image]

so is there any idea about how can i get my magento store product here?